# Install a Solr patch for TermVectors

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

I'm working with Solr 8.0 and I need to get the results of the TermsVectors in my code, but I can't use "tvrh" in my SolrQuery. I saw that I need to install a patch on my Solr, but I have no idea how to do this.

The link of the patch : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-949

Does anyone can help me with this ?

Thanks a lot

Alex

Comment: That patch is for a Solr version from back in 2009. It's over ten years old, and there is no chance it'll apply to Solr 8 without massive editing and adoption. You'll have to either make it work yourself or, better, ask about what you actually need Solr to return. There might be other ways to return the information you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, so the patch is a bad idea. The goal is to get the tf and df from the term vectors. I have some documents content in a field and the idea is to get each term of the documents with their tf (term frequency) and df (document frequency)

Comment: It seems both those values are returned by the TermVector Component? https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/the-term-vector-component.html

Comment: Exactly, that's the problem, I can't get the results using SolrJ https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/the-term-vector-component.html#solrj-and-the-term-vector-component

Comment: Then you can ask for the result to be returned as JSON and parse that response into an object. See https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/01/08/using-solr-cloud-for-robustness-but-returning-json-format/ for an example - I'll add it as an answer if it does what you need.

Comment: I'm not sure that it will work because the term vectors are outside the Solr's "response"
Anyway, I found this : https://github.com/ColinHebert/Sakai-Solr/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/org/sakaiproject/search/solr/response/TermVectorExtractor.java

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "outside the Solr's response" - _anything_ returned from the server, regardless of content as long as it's valid JSON, will be returned by parsing the response directly as JSON instead. But your find seems perfect; it should be part of the main SolrJ distribution. Add a link to the ticket if it's not already there so other people can be aware of it.

Comment: a part of the JSON that Solr returns is "response", it's basically what you get when you query Solr using SolrJ. 
And the term vectors seems a bit special because they're not part of the Solr response. Thanks for your help, I'll try to figure how the code I found works, if it's a good clue, I'll add it to this thread and close my question :)

Comment: Correct, I thought the JSON returned would be the whole request, not just the `response` part. I might be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found another way to solve my problem. 
I used the code below to get the term vectors and put them in an object, and it works pretty good.

Thanks a lot for your help.

https://github.com/ColinHebert/Sakai-Solr/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/org/sakaiproject/search/solr/response/TermVectorExtractor.java